# Stokes System: Laplacian of p implies that the velocity field is divergence-free?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, divergence-operator

I have the system formed by the equations of conservation of mass and momentum:
$$\mathrm{div}(\vec{v}) = 0 \tag1$$
$$\triangle\,\vec{v}=\vec{grad}\,p \tag2$$
Providing also their respective boundary conditions.

I have solved this system noting that because of the linearity and the commutativity of the Laplacian, in the second equation, one can take its divergence to obtain:
$$\triangle\,p=0 \tag3$$
Subjected to some additional boundary conditions.

My question is:

Can I assert that the solution given by equation $(2)$ once calculated the pressure distribution from $(3)$ fulfills $(1)$?

Thank you in advance for your answers.